# Find the radius of convergence of this $\ln$ series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+n)}{n^2}(x-1)^n$. a) Find the radius/interval of convergence and b) find if $x=\frac{e}{2}$ converges. c) does the series converge absolutely at every point in the interval of convergence.

a) First, using the ratio test, I successfully obtained the radius to be |x|<2 and that the interval is (-2, 1) (can someone check this please?)

b)To check if $x=\frac{e}{2}$makes the series above converge..I substituted $x=\frac{e}{2}$ and used the limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and found out that it diverges.

c) To check if the series converges absolutely in the interval (-2, 1), well, I think it diverges at points actually. I'm not sure about this but subbing in $x=0$ makes this an alternating series of $(-1)^n \frac{\ln(1+n)}{n^2}$, which does not converge using the ratio test.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic error is defining the convergence domain.  It is $|x-1|\le 1$ which is $[0,2]$.  For (b) $x=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is in the the interior.  For (c) $\sum \frac{ln(1+n)}{n^2}$ is absolutely convergent - need to use integral test (compare with $\int_1^\infty \frac{ln(1+x)}{x^2}dx$).

Comment: For  $n\ge 2$ we have $\ln (n+1)<\ln (n^2)$ and  $(\ln n)/\sqrt n =2(\ln \sqrt n)/\sqrt n <2$, and $(\ln (n+1))/n^2< (\ln (n^2))/n^2=2(\ln n)/n^2< 2(\sqrt n)/n^2 =2/n^{3/2}.$